# How to create a DataFrame from a dictionary with brackets and comma separated values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have created a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
my_dict=
(14, 'red', 'Bob')
(12, 'blue', 'Tom')
(68, 'green', 'Samantha')
(91, 'white', 'Jacob')
(113, 'yellow', 'Susy')
```

I'd like to turn this dictionary into a DataFrame, assigning labels to each column of my dictionary, like this:

```
NUMBER   COLOR    NAME
14       red      Bob
12       blue     Tom
68       green    Samantha
91       white    Jacob
113      yellow   Susy
```

I've tried `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)` but the DataFrame I get only contains the last row of my dictionary.

Comment: That's **not** a dictionary, it's a list of three-tuples (you could make a dictionary from a list of _two_-tuples, that's about as close as it gets).

Comment: That's not valid python making it difficult to come up with any concrete suggestions. If that was a list of tuples, then `pd.DataFrame(my_dict)` may be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, always note that **your data is not a dictionary**, just a list containing set of tuples, that's why your `from_dict()` method did not work. According to that, you can try this instead

```
# given list containing tuples that has 3 elements each
data = [(14, 'red', 'Bob'),
(12, 'blue', 'Tom'),
(68, 'green', 'Samantha'),
(91, 'white', 'Jacob'),
(113, 'yellow', 'Susy')]

# create DataFrame and specify your columns name
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['NUMBER', 'COLOR', 'NAME'])

# display DataFrame in Google Colab
df
```

Here is the result

```
   NUMBER   COLOR      NAME
0      14     red       Bob
1      12    blue       Tom
2      68   green  Samantha
3      91   white     Jacob
4     113  yellow      Susy
```

With this, your data will be in the format of dataframe, however, if you want to set your `NUMBER` column to be an index of the dataframe, you can simply do as follows :

```
# to set NUMBER column to be an index of your dataframe
df.set_index('NUMBER')
```

Hope this help !